# Can't change the property of an Object retrieved from localStorage

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using the following Snippet to retrieve an object previously stored in `localStorage` but for some reason when trying to modify it the object remains unmutable.

This is how I create the object:

```
if(typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
    if(!localStorage.Obj){
        localStorage.Obj = new Object();
    }
    var Obj = localStorage.Obj;

} else {
    if(!$.cookie("Obj")){
        $.cookie("Obj", new Object(), {
            expires : 7, // Days
            domain  : 'localhost:8080',
            secure  : true
        });
    }
    var Obj = $.cookie("Obj");
}
```

This is where I try to modify the object:

```
var login = function(email, passwd){

    $.ajax({
        url: "http://127.0.0.1/api/v1/login",
        type: "POST",
        data: { email: email, password: SHA256_hash(passwd), platform: getBrowserName(), osVersion: getOsName()},
        beforeSend: function(xhr){xhr.setRequestHeader('apiKey', "46d1e2f6-cf37-4275-bc1c-d674b12cc9bf");},
        success: function(data, status, xhr){
            Obj["logged_in"] = true;
            Obj["sessionKey"] = data.sessionKey;
            Obj["user_id"] = data.userID;
            Obj["time_format"] = data.timeFormat;
            Obj["first_name"] = data.firstName;
            Obj["last_name"] = data.lastName;
        },
        error: function(data, status, xhr){
            console.log(data);
        }
    });

    if(Obj.logged_in){
        window.location.replace("http://127.0.0.1/users/" + Obj.user_id + "/todos");
    }   
};
```

I need to point out 3 things:

- I'm using jQuery
- The 2 codes are in **different files** but the loading order is the correct.
- When using `console.log(Obj)` I get the following output: `"[object Object]"`
  Thanks in advance.

Comment: read up on how localStorage works... it only stores string data. You can convert using JSON.stringify() and JSON.parse()

Comment: I see, as soon as I converted to json String and loaded it, was working perfectly. Please add your answer as official answer so I can set it as correct for the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The underlying problem is that localStorage only stores string data.

For arrays and objects however they can be simply converted to string using `JSON.stringify()` and when pulling from localStorage the string can be converted to javascript object or array using `JSON.parse()`

A small library that is helpful is **[store.js](https://github.com/marcuswestin/store.js/)**

Answer (score 0):

[How do I correctly clone a JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728360/most-elegant-way-to-clone-a-javascript-object)

From Pascal's answer:
With jQuery, you can shallow copy with:

```
var copiedObject = jQuery.extend({}, originalObject)
```

subsequent changes to the copiedObject will not affect the originalObject, and vice versa.

Or to make a deep copy:

```
var copiedObject = jQuery.extend(true, {}, originalObject)
```